# Can Scenter "Sense" Mobs?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I have a mod called Scenter. What it does is you push a key that turns on Scenter, then it show you how close the block your scenting for. What I want to know is if Scenter can "sense" mobs, mainly Zombie Villagers and Wither Skeletons?
    `coal_ore 000000`
This is the config to search for coal ore, it will show a black line to the closest coal ore block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### No.

The [mod's official page](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1287428-1-7-10-forge-sp-mp-scenter-3-2-0-scent-out-hidden) does not mention the ability to track mobs.

Mobs are entities, which are very different from blocks, and can thus not be tracked with Scenter.